# How to open virtualenv in python3?

Tags: python, django, virtualenvwrapper

I have both python 2.7 and 3.8 installed in my computer but whenever I would install virtualenv using `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win` and then open a new virtualenv using `mkvirtualenv test` it says `Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2`. Now I downloaded django in the virtualenv and got the outdated version 1.11. So now I am unable to import path from django.urls among other things.

**Is there any way to install vitrualenwrapper with python3 interpreter?**
Please help. I am trying to learn django and this is creating a huge hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a virtual environment for any Python version by giving the python interpreter as an argument:

```
mkvirtualenv -p /path/to/python_binary test
```

Answer (score 6):

Virtualenv is already included in standard library of the Python3. You can create a virtual environment using the command below:

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

The second venv is the name of your virtualenv, you can name it as you want.

To use an existing virtualenv you should use the command:

```
path_to_your_venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

virtualenvwrapper should be installed into the same global site-packages area where virtualenv is installed. You may need administrative privileges to do that. The easiest way to install it is using pip:

```
 pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```

or:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```